# GCC Vector Extensions Sqrt

Tags: gcc, vectorization

I am currently experimenting with the [GCC vector extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).  However, I am wondering how to go about getting `sqrt(vec)` to work as expected.

As in:

```
typedef double v4d __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
v4d myfunc(v4d in)
{
    return some_sqrt(in);
}
```

and at least on a recent x86 system have it emit a call to the relevant intrinsic sqrtpd.  Is there a GCC builtin for sqrt that works on vector types or does one need to drop down to the intrinsic level to accomplish this?

Comment: Just do it like you would for an array.

Comment: This is somewhat suboptimal given that there is an ISA instruction specifically designed to sqrt root vectors which can potentially be twice as fast as two scalar square roots.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54408 I don't know of any workaround other than do it component-wise. The vector extensions were never meant to replace platform specific intrinsics anyway.

Comment: Post as an answer and I am more than happy to accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54408 I don't know of any workaround other than do it component-wise. The vector extensions were never meant to replace platform specific intrinsics anyway.

Some funky code to this effect:

```
#include <cmath>

#include <utility>

template <::std::size_t...> struct indices { };

template <::std::size_t M, ::std::size_t... Is>
struct make_indices : make_indices<M - 1, M - 1, Is...> {};

template <::std::size_t... Is>
struct make_indices<0, Is...> : indices<Is...> {};

typedef float vec_type __attribute__ ((vector_size(4 * sizeof(float))));

template <::std::size_t ...Is>
vec_type sqrt_(vec_type const& v, indices<Is...> const)
{
  vec_type r;

  ::std::initializer_list<int>{(r[Is] = ::std::sqrt(v[Is]), 0)...};

  return r;
}

vec_type sqrt(vec_type const& v)
{
  return sqrt_(v, make_indices<4>());
}

int main()
{
  vec_type v;

  return sqrt(v)[0];
}
```

You could also try your luck with auto-vectorization, which is separate from the vector extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the vectors directly

```
#include <math.h>
typedef double v2d __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));   
v2d myfunc(v2d in) {
    v2d out;
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) out[i] = sqrt(in[i]);
    return out;
}
```

The `sqrt` function has to trap for signed zero and NAN but if you avoid these with `-Ofast` both Clang and GCC produce simply `sqrtpd`.
https://godbolt.org/g/aCuovX

GCC might have a bug because I had to loop to 4 even though there are only 2 elements to get optimal code.

But with AVX and AVX512 GCC and Clang are ideal

AVX
https://godbolt.org/g/qdTxyp

AVX512
https://godbolt.org/g/MJP1n7

Comment: `-no-math-errno` is less drastic solution for GCC but not Clang https://godbolt.org/g/jQC8fe

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the question is that you want the square root of 4 packed double precision values... that's `32` bytes. Use the appropriate AVX intrinsic:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>

typedef double v4d __attribute__ ((vector_size (32)));
v4d myfunc (v4d v) {
    return _mm256_sqrt_pd(v);
}
```

---

[x86-64 gcc 10.2 and x86-64 clang 10.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/KvMjYn)
using `-O3 -march=skylake` :

```
myfunc:
  vsqrtpd %ymm0, %ymm0 # (or just `ymm0` for Intel syntax)
  ret
```

`ymm0` is the return value register.

**That said**, it just so happens there is a builtin: `__builtin_ia32_sqrtpd256`, which doesn't require the intrinsics header. I would definitely discourage its use however.

Comment: That wouldn’t work on an ARM Mac or iPhone.